# Why are two intersections of parabolas making the to values of phi?

Tags: conic-sections

When you graph **y=x^2-1** and **x=y^2-1** you get 4 intersections, being: (-1;0), (0;-1), (-0.618...;-0.618...) and (1.618...; 1.618...) the last two intersections are equal to phi, can you explain why this happens?

I have tried to solve these two equation, but I can't manage to solve them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the well-known relation $\phi+1=\phi^2$ (or numerically $1.618034\cdots^2=2.618034\cdots$), you draw that

$$\phi^2-1=\phi.$$

Hence $(\phi,\phi)$ belongs to both curves.

And dividing by $-\phi^2$,

$$\left(-\frac1\phi\right)^2-1=-\frac1\phi.$$

---

The explicit resolution is by means of

$$x=y^2-1=(x^2-1)^2-1$$ or

$$x^4-2x^2-x=x(x+1)(x^2-x-1)=0.$$

Answer (score 0):

To find the intersections, we have to solve this system of two equations:
$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
y=x^2-1
\\x=y^2-1
\end{matrix}\right.$$
We can substract the second equation to the first and we have:
$$y-x=x^2-y^2\leftrightarrow (x-y)(x+y+1)=0 \leftrightarrow x=y \vee x=-(y+1)$$
Substituing, we have:
$$y=y^2-1 \vee y=(y+1)^2-1$$
In the first case, we have:
$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
y=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{5}}{2}=\pm \phi
\\x=y=\pm\phi
\end{matrix}\right.$$
In the second case, we arrive at:
$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
y=0 \vee y=-1
\\x=-(y+1)=-1 \vee x=-(y+1)=0
\end{matrix}\right.$$